# Puppeteer is not working the same on local vs prod

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
let templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(process.cwd(), '../signedDocs/template.html'),
    'utf8'
);
// making a compilable out of the HTML file
let template = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
console.log('creafte pdf 1');
// passing the data to the HTML
let html = template(dataPDF);

// constructing the path where the generated PF file will be stored
let pdfPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '../signedDocs/' + userID + '.pdf');
console.log('creafte pdf 2');
// PDF configuration
let options = {
    width: '1230px',
    headerTemplate: '<p></p>',
    footerTemplate: '<p></p>',
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    printBackground: true,
    pageRanges: '1-6',
    format: 'A4',
    preferCSSPageSize: true,
    margin: {
        top: '10px',
        right: '20px',
        bottom: '60px',
        left: '20px'
    },
    path: pdfPath
};

console.log('creafte pdf 3.1');
// starting the browser with Puppeteer
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    headless: true
});
console.log('creafte pdf 3.2');
// starting a new blank page
let page = await browser.newPage();

try {
    await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0' //command used so the page w/ modules waited to be loaded
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
console.log('creafte pdf 4');
try {
    await page.pdf(options); // to generate the PDF
} catch (err) {
    console.log('errrr   on  page.pdf');
    console.log(err);
}

console.log('done');
await followUpEmail(user);
console.log('email sent');
await browser.close(); // for closing the browser
```

The above code works perfectly fine on my localhost. ( Running node.js 10 )

However i have now deployed my API to an EC2 instance and it runs until:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    headless: false
});
```

I get the 3.1 console.log but nothing afterwards.

Im starting to get the feeling its something todo with my Prod env. However after trying all type of different approaches today i'm a bit lost.

Now i'm really hoping someone here has encountered this issue and has an answer or a direction!

Comment: are all the library and node versions same?

Comment: any why is headless: false? if headless is false then you might require some additional libraries to work in ec2

Comment: Yes, all latest versions and ive tried it with both headless: true and false.

Comment: Is there any tutorial you followed while setting up puppeteer in ec2 if yes can you share that? Normally ec2 doesn't have the capability to launch puppetter in the background. You need to install at-least a handful of libraries from DIFFERENT DISTROS to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that NPM does install a version of Chrome however its missing a-lot of dependancies.

I checked to see which dependancies were missing by using:

```
ldd chrome | grep not
```

Installed a few manually however some are not on the PKM's

I then created a YUM config to install chrome, installed it and that came with the missing dependancies.